# Delete database entry after reading it?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a problem with my PHP Script. I use JQuery to read out the sourcecode of the PHP file. 
Unfortunately the value in the database will not be deleted when I call the script with JQuery. My script:

```
$ergebnis = mysql_query("SELECT value FROM Table WHERE id='$user'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($ergebnis))
{
echo $row->value;
}
$eintragen = mysql_query("UPDATE Table SET value ='' WHERE id='$user'");
```

How can I delete the database entry (value in the table) after reading it?
The Query works in PHPMyAdmin but not in the script.

Comment: Where is your DELETE Query?

Comment: Sorry, I mean delete the value.

Comment: is `value` allowed to be null?

Comment: What to do with jQuery then? why have you tagged jQuery here in the question?

Comment: @Jai well, the OP did say "I use JQuery to read out the sourcecode of the PHP file." However, it's not really relevant to the question..

Comment: null is allowed. It works if I try it in PHPMyAdmin. Just the PHP Script does not work.

Comment: There might just be a naming conflict using value as your row name, try escaping or renaming

Comment: I don't see a `commit` in your code.

Comment: What do yoou mean with commit?

Answer (score 0):

```
$eintragen = mysql_query("DELETE FROM Table WHERE id='$user' LIMIT 1");
```

That will delete it - assuming id is unique.

Always put 'LIMIT 1' on a query that will only affect one row in case you make a mistake!

Comment: LIMIT 1 is ok for initial tasks, but always isn't the right way to put it. A normalized database query by primary key or foreign key, and if the relationship is kept, LIMIT 1 will be redundant.

Comment: yup - but then again you are talking about beautifully structured databases - most people's are not! - but as I said it is a safety feature! I have written a query before, cocked it up and deleted 1000s of rows - plus if someone manages to run your query who shouldn't the LIMIT 1 is another little step that can help avoid catastrophe (but not much)

Comment: If most peoples databases are not normalized I weep for our Computer Science education. If somebody is running code that they shouldn't be, that's a whole other security issue in itself lol